# Apple TV doesn't play some youtube movies

Tags: appletv

I put this [Samsara movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNkLdEEuwv4&index=3&list=FLQrxcO4EyMsVw2_QZU5i0WA) into my youtube favourites.

There are two unexpected issues here.

- If I try to play that movie either from iPad or iPhone and display it to my Apple TV my Apple TV said that it can't play this movie.
- The other strange issue is that the above movie isn't shown amongst the favorites on my Apple TV. However the youtube web interface clearly shows that it is my favorite.

This [version of Baraka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIS0-ZJ7yXA&list=FLQrxcO4EyMsVw2_QZU5i0WA&index=4) which is not Full HD can be played, but still doesn't show amongst my favourites despite the fact that it is there on the web UI:

Any explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some insides.

It comes in different resolution/Sizes.

166 Mb, 259 MB, 588 Mb and 1.05 Gig (1080p Full HD)

If the Add to Play list or Streaming to Apple TV is not working!

[image: play list]

In situation like that I use the Ant-Player add on in Firefox and download the movie.

But, just to say, I can add it to my play list and stream! You should try to let it play for few minutes first since it is very slow to start and then try to stream to your Apple TV.

Comment: Did you manage to play and stream the Samsara movie to your appleTV? If yes then how?

Comment: Yes it worked for me, see my answer for how. at http://youtu.be/oNkLdEEuwv4

Answer (score 0):

The reason your favourites do not appear in the listing on the Apple TV is that the owner of the video has not allowed it to be viewed on a mobile device (which the youtube considers the apple TV to be). The Apple TV recognises this and removes it from the list so you do not try and play an unplayable video.

The owner of the video (or more probably the copyright owner of the soundtrack) can decide whether to allow mobile devices and Apple TV's to display videos.

Comment: I tried to stream this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNkLdEEuwv4&index=3&list=FLQrxcO4EyMsVw2_QZU5i0WA
 to my apple TV but it didn't work